# rectangle vs image performance during animations

Tags: image, qt, animation, qml

Consider I have a QML rectangle of width 'w' and height 'h', colored all black. I also have an image of black color having same width and height.

I need to perform some animations on these two.
Will there be an advantage in performance in choosing one over the other?
What and how much of a role will resolution of the image play in making this decision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If animations not involve scaling, most likely there will no noticeable difference. You can try to do measurements using QML profiler in latest creator.

http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2012/02/07/qml-profiler-update/